# How prevent this loop?

Tags: c#, loops

I cannot figure out how to fix this loop issue when i call a function like

```
new Common.Utility.Parameter().Get(Common.Constants.Parameter.SomeParameter);
```

Probably the error is caused by `isHttpsCookie` that recall the `Parameter.Get()`

Utility.cs

```
public static class Utility
{
    public class Parameter
    {
        public string Get(string key)
        {
            string cookie = new Cookie().Read(key);
            if (cookie == null)
            {
                var parameter = new Models.Parameter();
                using (var db = new MyEntities())
                    parameter = db.Parameters.Where(w => w.Key == key).FirstOrDefault<Models.Parameter>();
                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    new Cookie().Write(key, parameter.Value);
                    return parameter.Value;
                }
                else
                    return string.Empty;
            }
            else
                return cookie;
        }
    }
}
```

Cookie.cs

```
public class Cookie
{
    private bool isHttpsCookie = Convert.ToBoolean(new Utility.Parameter().Get(Constants.Parameter.IsHttps)); // Loop here?

    public string Read(string cookieName)
    {
        HttpCookie httpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType().BaseType.Assembly.GetName().Na​me + "_" + cookieName];
        return httpCookie != null ? HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(httpCookie.Value).Trim() : string.Empty;
    }

    public void Write(string cookieName, string cookieValue, bool isHttpCookie = true)
    {
        if (isHttpsCookie)
            isHttpCookie = false;

        var aCookie = new HttpCookie(HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.GetType().BaseType.Assembly.G​etName().Name + "_" + cookieName)
                          {Value = cookieValue, Expires = Common.Constants.Cookie.DefaultExpires, HttpOnly = isHttpCookie};
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: which loop? what is your problem exactly?

Comment: When I call "new Common.Utility.Parameter().Get(Common.Constants.Parameter.SomeParameter);" I receive following error "System.StackOverflowException". Possible cause is on cookie class that recall parameter function, but i dont know how to fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in what you suspect. the isHttpsCookie declaration is causing you grief.

When the Cookie object is created it goes away and executes the method get from your utility class which creates an instance of cookie. Therefor you have your recursion.

You will need to change the way you initialise isHttpsCookie. Maybe only initialise / check if you are doing a write. After all you are most likely going to read more often than write.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your code is falling into a sort of recursion where you suspect it is. What I'm having trouble with is why are you creating new objects just to call a single method. Looks like you could have them as static methods in your classes, so no object creation would be needed, thus no 'looping'.

Answer (score 1):

Have a closer look at your Cookie.Write() and Parameter.Get() method, they are calling each other. When you declare `isHttpsCookie`, you call `Parameter.Get()`. In the `Parameter.Get()`, if the condition is valid, it will call to `Cookie.Write()`. In its turn, when you call `new Cookie()`, the `isHttpsCookie` is called again and it's continuing forever.

Another point at this code:

```
if (isHttpsCookie)
        isHttpCookie = false;
```

do you try to say that isHttpsCookie should be false at all time? so why do you need to declare this?

Solution: Do like @Takeshi said: those methods can be declared as static so no class declaration is required to called them.

Comment: Hi Wery! Thanks both you and Takeshi for suggestion. isHttpsCookie can be true or false, depending on deploy environment (if production environament so https)